# Xcode4 show all output (remove "Showing first 200 notices only")

Tags: xcode

New bug Apple added to Xcode4 latest version: if there's more than 200 lines of output, it's all deleted.

Obviously, if there's output, it's there for a reason, and I need to see it :(.

I tried looking for a Preference, or a GUI, or a button, but can't find anything.

Surely they didn't hardcode it to prevent you seeing your own output? :)

Comment: Are you referring to the build output? If so, you could try building from the commandline. e.g. $xcodebuild -project <yourproject.xcodeproj>

Comment: Well ... yes ... and you could "not use Xcode at all, write everything in Notepad". If you have to stop using xcode and run xcodebuild from the commandline every time you want to do a build ... it's not much help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem with output from a custom build script.  Looking at the Log Navigator, if I select the "Run custom shell script..." line that I'm interested in, a button with several horizontal lines appears on the right of that line.  Clicking this button shows all the output from my script.  Even the output past that 200 line limit.

It's a bit cumbersome to read through like this, but you can right click to copy it out for pasting into the text editor of your choice.

Here's what the button looks like in the log navigator:

[image: The log navigator line for my shell script, showing the]

Comment: Please note that in the text version it will still show "Showing first 200 notices only" even though it actually shows everything. This being in Xcode 6.1.1. What a mess :S

Answer (score 10):

[image: Click on Expand All Transcripts]

Right click on the Run custom shell script and then click on Expand All Transcripts

Comment: Doesn't work, it still abbreviates with "Showing first 200 notices only"

Answer (score 0):

Select **Show the issue navigator** in left side pane ,select the target, if you have any linker warning or Dsymutil Warning , click anyone of that, you should be able to see the list of all the warning, filter it with by selecting "**ALL**" and "**ALL Issues**" in right side pane. You will now be able to see total warnings with details.[image]