# Xcode4 show all output (remove “Showing first 200 notices only”) in Terminal

Tags: unit-testing, logging, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

we're using xcodebuild for some Jenkins CI tasks.

We have an error that stops the build, but can't see what it is because xcodebuild limits the log length to the first 200 notices:

```
Showing first 200 notices only

** TEST FAILED **
```

Is there a way to remove the 200 notice limit? We know we can do this in Xcode using the UI, but need to be able to do it from the command line with xcodebuild

Comment: Hmm? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619408/xcode4-show-all-output-remove-showing-first-200-notices-only

Comment: That's from the Xcode GUI. We need to be able to set this in terminal from where we run xcodebuild.

Comment: Ok. I misread the suggested answer. Maybe Xcode upgrade? What is the command You execute?

Answer (score 0):

Just use xcodebuild cli. 
In Jenkins set "invoke script" step with following content:
xcodebuild clean test -project SOMEPROJECT.xcodeproj -scheme SOMECHEME -destination 'name=iPhone 6,OS=9.1'

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do this in one of the following ways:

a. Add this in your configuration files. OTHER_CFLAGS (Other C Flags)
    e.g. OTHER_CFLAGS=-ferror-limit=0

b. GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS (Preprocessor Macros)
c. INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS (Info.plist Preprocessor Definitions)

Answer (score 0):

If in Xcode you want to try, Select **Show the issue navigator** in left side pane ,select the target, if you have any linker warning or Dsymutil Warning , click anyone of that, you should be able to see the list of all the warning, filter it with by selecting "**ALL**" and "**ALL Issues**" in right side pane. You will now be able to see total warnings with details.[image]